# How do I set a value as a string React-Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I am setting up a new token value with react native fetch method and ı take the token value which is 'AGFsdkhgdgdkFSADLfksdgk' for example.
I want to use this token with string value how ?

I am also tried get and set method but it is not necessary. For example ı have a string value which is '_token'. I want to use this _token value every class when ı using get method for reading data.

**Here is my fetch method function.**

```
_getToken () {
    const data = {
        grant_type: "",
        branchcode: "",
        password: "",
        username: "",
        dbname: "",
        dbuser: "",
        dbpassword: "",
        dbtype: ""
    }
    return (
        fetch('http:/192.168.1.29:7070/api/v2/token', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: qs.stringify(data)
        }).then(response => response.json())
            .then(responseData => {
                console.log(responseData['access_token']);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("HATA!!!" + error);
            })
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use AsyncStorage for store access token like this :

```
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';

AsyncStorage.setItem('token',responseData['access_token']);
```

and use it like this :

```
  AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then((value)=>{
 console.log(value) //value is stored token
})
```

Comment: How can ı use this ? when ı use this await function ı take an error like 'Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function'

Comment: use AsyncStorage with then

Comment: can u show me inside in my own code how to use asyncStorage ?

Comment: To use `await` inside function, you have to declare the function as `async`. For example:
`async getToken() { return await AsyncStorage.getItem('token') }`

Comment: 1-   import "AsyncStorage" from react-native , 2- set token to AsyncStorage when fetch response , 3- use token in every where with  "AsyncStorage.getItem"